# Q, request and promises, request middleware not jumping into callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js, httpwebrequest

Hey guys I am using q and request middleware in node. I'm making a http request. with a service helper. Every service call works fine except when I am making this call

This is the service call and the constucted url is 100% right and I get a json if I visit the url.

```
var MovieService = require('./movieservice.js');
    MovieService.getContent(config.themoviedbimdbid + 'tt' + imdbid + '?external_source=imdb_id&api_key=' + config.themoviedbkey).then(function (data) {
        var result = JSON.parse(data);
    });
```

and this is the service helper witch dosent jump into request callback function and I don't know why...

```
var q = require('q');
var request = require('request');

var Service = {
    getContent: function(url) {
        var deferred = q.defer();
        request(url, function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                deferred.resolve(body);
            } else {
                deferred.reject(error);
            }
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
};

module.exports = Service;
```

P.s. The service is working for every thing else
Please help thank you

Comment: Ohh yeah the request callback always jumps straight to return deferred.promise instead of callback

Comment: you are not handling error conditions in your call to getContent. I would add `.catch(function(err) { console.log(err)})` chained after your `then` call, and see if it says anything

Comment: i did that, but got null